# jQuery UI Sortable "portlets" - triggering placeholder specifics?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have an implementation of an application that uses jQuery UI Sortable in a "portlets" style interface, like their example here: http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#portlets

I am having a bit of a problem making the "target" placeholder become visible with true consistency. I have 4 sortable containers: 1 that is full width, followed by 2 that are 50% width, followed by another that is full width. The idea is that the user can make a "portlet" full-sized by dragging it into one of the 100% areas.

It works.

However, I can't reliably make the top "placeholder" appear. I move the mouse around, move it over other portlets, and *sometimes* it will appear so that I can drop the widget in there.

I just want to eliminate the "sometimes" variable. Of the many behaviour parameters offered by the Sortable interaction, which ones do I need to tune? Also is there any relevant CSS that factors in? (padding, etc).

I would provide sample code, but it's not practical.. I'm calling with defaults:

`$('.widgetContainer').sortable({connectWith: ".widgetContainer"});`

As for CSS, there's a chain of inheritance on the site such that it will be tricky (though not impossible of course) for me to isolate. Suffice it to say, these rules are in place at least:

```
.placeholder { float: left; margin-bottom: 10px; }
.widgetContainer { float: left; padding-bottom: 20px; }
```